# Should I use IsoHybrid for booting Flash Drives?

Tags: linux

I was recently trying to load a 'live-distro' .iso onto a flash drive,
to I hopefully install it to my carbon x1 3 gen laptop.

My question is should I use syslinux isohybrid on the image first?
Does it matter? or can I just dd the image direct to the flash drive 
an it will be bootable straight away?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a live image, just `dd` it to a flash drive. I prefer to do it with these 2 options: `bs=8M` and `conv=fsync`.